# multirow command doesn't close entire cell in table environment

Tags: tables, multirow

I want to make a table using the command `\multirow` but, when compiling, the last horizontal line does not close all the texts in the cells, the word Early-time does not fit inside the cell, any help please?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\caption{Classification of singularities for the case of late-time}
\begin{tabular}{| m{1.4cm} |  m{1.7cm}|m{1.7cm} | m{2cm}  | }
\hline\multirow{1}{1cm}[0cm]{\centering\textbf{Solution}}  & \multirow{1}{1.7cm}[0cm]{\centering\textbf{Late-Time}} & 
\multirow{1}{1.7cm}[0cm]{\centering\textbf{Early-Time}} &
\multirow{1}{1.7cm}[0cm]{\centering\textbf{Condition}}\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \label{tabla2}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may give the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) a try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Classification of singularities for the case of late-time}
  \label{tabla2}
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {|Q[m,c,1.4cm]|Q[m,c,1.7cm]|Q[m,c,1.7cm]|Q[m,c,2cm]|},
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  }
    \hline
      Solution & Late-Time & Early-Time & Condition \\ 
    \hline
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! but overleaf can't find the package tabularray , what can I do?

Comment: Download `tabularray.sty` and `ninecolors.sty`  from CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray and https://ctan.org/pkg/ninecolors

Comment: thanks for the help, but i can't upload that package to overleaf, apparently it doesn't recognize it, what can i do? I start to despair ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't use overleaf. But you can put these two sty files in the same folder as your tex file.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{multirow,array,booktabs,makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Classification of singularities for the case of late-time}
\begin{tabular}{| m{1.7cm} |  m{1.7cm}|m{1.7cm} | m{2cm}  |}
\hline
{\multirow{1.6}{*}{\textbf{Solution}}}  
    &{\textbf{\makecell[c]{Late-\\Time}}} 
        &{\textbf{\makecell[c]{Early-\\Time}}} 
            &{\multirow{1.6}{*}{\textbf{Condition}}}\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \label{tabla2}
\end{table}

{\ttfamily OR -- with booktabs package and no verticals}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Classification of singularities for the case of late-time}
\begin{tabular}{ m{1.7cm}   m{1.7cm} m{1.7cm}  m{2cm}  }
\toprule
{\multirow{1.6}{*}{\textbf{Solution}}}  
    &{\textbf{\makecell[c]{Late-\\Time}}} 
        &{\textbf{\makecell[c]{Early-\\Time}}} 
            &{\multirow{1.6}{*}{\textbf{Condition}}}\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \label{tabla2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Classification of singularities for the case of late-time}
  \label{tabla2}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{m[c]{14mm}m[c]{17mm}m[c]{17mm}m[c]{2cm}}[hvlines]
    \RowStyle{\bfseries}
    Solution & Late-Time & Early-Time & Condition \\ 
  \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]